# Why does it says me "Expected primary expression." on the line with "memory"?

Tags: solidity

```js
contract Contract {
    function main() {
        
        memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;
    
        if (msg.data.length < 0x04) { revert(memory[0x00:0x00]); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That is a decompilation output.

Your compiler will not understand that code because is not valid Solidity, this is just a simple language to show what the contract will do when it receives a request.

`main()` is the entry point to the smart contract.

The `if (msg.data.length < 0x04)` part is checking that the data sent to the smart contract has at least 4 bytes, which is the function selector.
With this, it's clear that that smart contract does not have a `fallback` function because if it did, then it would not check the length of the data.

For example, I compiled and decompiled a smart contract with a `fallback` function and that line is different because since the contract now has a `fallback` function, then it's optional to send data and if you don't send it, it means you want to call the `fallback` function:

```js
function main() {
        memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;
    
       if (msg.data.length < 0x04) {
            var var0 = storage[0x00];
            var var1 = 0x00;
            var var2 = var1;
            var var4 = var0;
            var var3 = 0x0040;
            var3 = func_00DC(var4);
        
        label_0040:
            storage[var1] = var3;
            stop();
        }
//...
}
```

So, it will not revert because it knows that there is a `fallback` function to route the request to in case no data is sent.

The `memory[0x40:0x60] = 0x80;` part just means to point to the free memory pointer: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/internals/layout_in_memory.html#layout-in-memory

The contract that I compiled and decompiled was:

```js
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.6;

contract Counter {

    uint256 public counter;

    function updateCounter() public {
        counter++;
    }

    fallback() external payable {
        counter++;
    }

}
```

Its runtime bytecode is:

```
60806040526004361061002d5760003560e01c80631687fe8e1461004757806361bc221a1461005e5761002e565b5b600080815480929190610040906100dc565b9190505550005b34801561005357600080fd5b5061005c610089565b005b34801561006a57600080fd5b506100736100a2565b60405161008091906100b7565b60405180910390f35b60008081548092919061009b906100dc565b9190505550565b60005481565b6100b1816100d2565b82525050565b60006020820190506100cc60008301846100a8565b92915050565b6000819050919050565b60006100e7826100d2565b91507fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff82141561011a57610119610125565b5b600182019050919050565b7f4e487b7100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000600052601160045260246000fdfea26469706673582212200943c97545408f10c291db440fbd3fc1d326915ea04cc933be2fa6eec196958d64736f6c63430008060033
```

You can decompile it here and check: https://ethervm.io/decompile

You can play around with a smart contract, adding the `fallback` function, `receive`, function, and some other things and compile/decompile them and analyze to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

Because inline assembly doesnt look anything like that. That looks more like decompiler output. What are you trying to do exactly here?